# DataGridView Image Layout Stretch Bug

Tags: c#, image, layout, datagridview

I'm using a `DataGridView` to display some data, including an image which I'm displaying in an "Image Column". To display the image properly, I set the `Image Layout` property to `Stretch`; however, I'm getting an unexpected visual effect when I click on a row or I scroll (up-down, left-right).

- When I scroll, it look like the background keep a "picture" of the
  movement.
- When I click, the background seems to stack.

[image]

Given that I set the `Image Layout` property at design time, I thought the way I set it created this bug. So I tried to set the property at run time, but I had no luck.

Then I started to think it was probably another property set with "Image Layout:stretch" that can make this issue. I tried to find the property, but I found nothing to fix it.

I did not show code because I don't think it is pertinent in my situation. But if you think it is, let me know and I will post what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a transparent background image(like .png image format) that ways you are facing that type of problem.
Another issue is may be you have low graphics in your system.